# I want to know what's the root cause of the compile error. Which one takes precedence over the other?

Tags: java

There is a code fragment:

```java
class CD {

    int r;

    CD(int r) {
        this.r = r;

    }
}

class DVD extends CD {

    int c;

    DVD(int r, int c) {
        // line n1
    }
}
```

And given the code fragment:

```
DVD dvd = new DVD(10, 20);
```

Which code fragment should you use at line n1 to instantiate the dvd object successfully?

**A**

```
super.r = r;
this.c = c;
```

**B**

```
super(r);
this(c);
```

**C**

```
super(r);
this.c = c;
```

**D**

```
this.c = r;
super(c);
```

Correct answer is **C**.

I have a question about **B**:

1. `this(c)` isn't the first statement in that constructor( `DVD(int r, int c)`)
2. there isn't a one-parameter constructor in **class DVD**, `this(c)` can't call it.

**I want to know what's the root cause of the compile error. Which one takes precedence over the other**?

Eclipse Error:
[image: 图片说明]

IDEA Error:
[image: 图片说明]

Comment: "I want to know what's the root cause of the compile error." It's simply invalid code.

Comment: Does it matter which error the compiler identifies first? Both are errors that prevent the code from passing compilation.

Answer (score 0):

The errors are simple:

- you can only have **one** call to another constructor within a constructor. Calling `super()` and `this()` is thus invalid.
- as you figured yourself: the usage of `this()` isn't valid because there is no single-argument constructor in the corresponding class

A distinct non answer for the second part of the question:

> I want to know what's the root cause of the compile error. Which one takes precedence over the other

That is actually an implementation detail. You see, the only thing that matters from the outside of a compiler is the language specification that determine what the compiler accepts, what that input "means" and therefore what the output should be about.

Conclusion: there is no clearly specified "order" of errors. The compiler gets implemented in whatever way looks appropriate for the people writing it. So if error X is detected prior Y, as said, that solely depends on the implementation. Another compiler might tell you about Y first.

Obviously, there might be a "natural" order in which things get looked at, leading to similar behavior, but you can (and should) not make any assumptions about such behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to instantiate a subclass, where the parent class has only one constructor taking an int parameter.

Unless there is a default constructor, you have to explicitly invoke a constructor of the parent class, via `super(...)`, and [this has to be the first statement in the constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.7).

Straight away, that eliminates `A` (which doesn't invoke a constructor) and `D` (which invokes `super` second).

An invocation of `this(...)` also has to be the first statement in a constructor - this necessarily means that you can't invoke both `super(...)` and `this(...)` in the same constructor (nor can you invoke `this(...)` twice). So that eliminates `B`.